# How to Use PurifyCSS in Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix, purifycss

I want to use [PurifyCSS](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss) in Laravel but I can't get it to work.

**Stack**

> Laravel: 5.5.4
>
> NPM: 6.0.0
>
> Node.js: 8.10

**Code**

```js
mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/panel/a.css',
    'resources/assets/css/panel/b.css',
    'resources/assets/css/panel/c.css',
    'resources/assets/css/panel/d.css',
], 'public/css/panel.css').options({
    purifyCss: {
        purifyOptions: {
            info: true,
            rejected: true,
            minify: true
        },
        paths: ['resources/views/admin-layout.blade.php'],
        verbose: true
    },
});
```

I searched on the internet but couldn't find anything. I want to strip unused CSS from all Blade pages. Even on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074941/purifying-css-assets-via-laravel-mix-doesnt-work), nobody answered with the correct answer. Even if PurifyCSS is first, it's not working.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

First install PurgeCSS.

```
npm install laravel-mix-purgecss --save-dev
```

Declaring the `mix` variable and setting your options is relatively simple.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .purgeCss();
```

In this code, `purgeCss()` will remove unused CSS from your compiled CSS files. By default, it will scan your resources/views directory for Blade templates and your resources/js directory for JavaScript or Vue components.

Comment: PurifyCSS support is no longer available. We recommend using PurgeCss + postCss instead. @KarlHill